# Has many return null value laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many, laravel-7

I'm having a problem with laravel's OnetoMany feature. My goal is to retrieve the different codes of a user :
Code Model :

```
 public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Users');
}
```

User model :

```
    public function code(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Code');
}
```

And my controller :

```
        $users= Users::find($id);
    dd($users->codes);
```

But this function is returning "null".
I can retrieve my user's data but not the associated codes.
Thank for your help !

Comment: Double check the reference id and primary key of the tables `code` and `users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should rename the code relation in user model to be plural:

```
public function codes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Code');
}
```

and then:

```
  $user= Users::with('codes')->find($id);
    dd($user->codes);
```

please note that find retrieve only one user so name the variable '$user' not '$users'

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues in your code:

- `$users = Users::find($id)` returns a *single record* with the corresponding `$id` so naming
  it `$users` is a little misleading.
- In your question your model class is defined as **User** but when calling
  it with `find()` you defined it as **Users**,  don't know which one is right but all
  models names should be *single*, so `User` **not** `Users`.
- in your **User** model the name of the function is `code()`  but you
  call it as `$users->codes` that's wrong it should be `$users->code`.